# Cant find reference for button, kotlin library

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HDxX.png)I just have this:

```
package com.example.world

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        button.setOnClickListener() {
            // Do some work here
        }
    }
}
```

But on this line:

```
  button.setOnClickListener() {
            // Do some work here
        }
```

it says:

```
Unresolved reference: button
```

And I dont see the hint for important the correct library.

So what kind of library I have to import then?

Thank you

if I do it like this:

```
 val btn_click = findViewById(R.id.button) as Button

        btn_click.setOnClickListener(){
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "YOu clicked on me", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

Then it works.

But that is not necessarily I have read.

You dont have to make a referenct to the button.

So you just can do this:

button.setOnClickListener... but what is the correct library for that?

Comment: Well, where is the button? If it's in the layout, you either need to obtain the `Button` instance by calling `findViewById`, or use [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

Comment: Yes, I have the button. With the id button

Comment: You have probably looked at some code that used the old Kotlin Android Extensions plugin. That is now deprecated, and you should use view binding instead (or just use the old-school `findViewById`).

Comment: @Michael. Ah, oke. Thank you. Yes, that is it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 'abstract' button, you need to find it in layout by element id (You can have many buttons in your layout, how you will find correct button without id?) If you wouldn't like to find layout elements by id, you can take a look on Android View Binding here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding.

Comment: I have id on the button. SO yes, I want to find element with id.

Comment: You wrote this "Then it works.

But that is not necessarily I have read.

You dont have to make a referenct to the button.

So you just can do this:

button.setOnClickListener... but what is the correct library for that?" If you want, as you wrote, to find element by id use findViewById. I don't understand the problem. If you don't - take a look on Android View Binding Library.

Comment: I just want to use button and not findViewById. because with button. setOnClickListener the code is much cleaner and shorter

Comment: It's impossible without using some external library. Take a look on Android View Binding Library or some external libraries like ButterKnife https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Comment: What I mean is how can I use button.setOnClickListener